# Scenario/Method (idea) for transfering database from one server to another

Tags: mysql, linux

The scenario is next.
Every day on linux mysql server script copy from samba share wich is "/var/lib/mysql/db2223" to another backup server over network lets say windows server. Database has lets say 200 GB of data.

One day linux mysql server get down and cannot be fixed.

Method: Take another machine install on it linux server configure and then create again in phpmyadmin only name of db "db2223" and copy all from backup to new "var/lib/mysql/db2223" directory.

Is this method good or bad ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using InnoDB, the "backup" is *useless*.  `ibdata1` is needed.  And there are other issues.

If you are using MyISAM, it will probably work.